# Inserting jQuery corresponding to a certain element ID

Tags: blocks, javascript, theming

I have a website in which I want to apply a custom drop down menu to a block. However, I have no idea how to go about doing this.

I posted this yesterday and came to the agreement that the jquery was to be added from a separate location, but I do not know where to implement it! I was wondering if perhaps this should be added to the /modules/block/ location or if it should be called elsewhere.

The content that I want to edit may be seen at mag-ds.com in the lower portion (the entries with #id=T_roll.

Help?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a javascript file from a module or a theme, whatever is most appropriate. For scripts that should be loaded on (nearly) all pages, just add a line to the .info file of your module or theme:

```
scripts[] = somescript.js
```

For scripts that you only want to load in certain occasions, use the drupal_add_js module. See [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722) for details.

That said, there are a lot of modules out there for drop down menus, so that may even be easier. Check [Comparison of various drop down menus](http://drupal.org/node/990154) for instance, or simply search drupal.org or drupalmodules.com.